# Calculate Time from Database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, time, calculation

I am trying to make my program calculate a break time with data stored in an `mysql` database.

```
private void timerpause_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();
            conn.Open();

            MySqlCommand dbrequest = conn.CreateCommand();
            dbrequest.CommandText = "SELECT pstart FROM arbeitszeiten WHERE fullname = '" + textBoxfullname.Text + "' and active = 'JA'";
            string pausebeginn = dbrequest.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            MySqlCommand dbrequest2 = conn.CreateCommand();
            dbrequest2.CommandText = "SELECT ptotal FROM arbeitszeiten WHERE fullname = '" + textBoxfullname.Text + "' and active = 'JA'";
            string pausenzeit = dbrequest2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            TimeSpan pause = Convert.ToDateTime(pausenzeit).TimeOfDay;
            DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(pausebeginn);
            TimeSpan zwischen = (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(start)).Add(pause);


            label1.Text = zwischen.ToString();

            conn.Close();
        }
```

When the code is executed it tells me:

```
TimeSpan pause = Convert.ToDateTime(pausenzeit).TimeOfDay;
```

The charters are not detected as a valid `DateTime` value (Die Zeichenfolge wurde nicht als gültiges DateTime erkannt)

Format:

```
 DB pstart = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
 DB ptotal = HH:mm:ss
```

Does anyone see my mistake (besides not having the requests parameterized yet)?

Comment: What are the schema types for `pstart` and `ptotal`? Hopefully they are not string types but some type of date or time type in which case you do not have to convert to string and then parse. It would also mean you can do the calculation as a sql statement instead of in the code with 2 round trip statements.

Comment: if i understood you right, you are asking for the datatyp in db and where it comes from ? its timestamp for pstart and time for ptotal. pstart is passed over automaticaly on press of an button, ptotal is calculated within the db it self

Comment: So you could probably use a [date function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to calculate `zwischen` as a query and then return that directly. You should also not call `ToString` on these results as they are probably converted for you to type DateTime, DateTimeOffset or TimeSpan. I don't use MySql so you will have to test to figure out which one of these native types is used by default for each MySql type.

Comment: I suspect the quick fix is because the time isn't a date, so you could convert it to a date by appending a basic date first, e.g. Convert.ToDateTime("2000-01-01 " + pausenzeit).TimeOfDay

Comment: At least in the case of `pstart` if the database stored a Date you would not need the gymnatics of converting `ToString` then `Convert.ToDateTime`, just read it as a DateTime.  The "format" notice though indicates it might be stored as string

Comment: Allright, Thanks for the answers so far. iam gonna try all of that out tomorrow. To give more information here is an screenshot of the datatyp the db safes the values in: http://fiftysnens.com/img/unbenannt.png

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone else here that the best case scenario is that your dates should be stored as dates.I am going to make some assumptions. One that your database is out of your control or too time consuming/ not a priority to deal with for what ever reason. So i will assume that makes your question how vest to parse your dates and time spans in those formats. Im also going to assume you deal with nulls and format exceptions for dodgy data separately.

Personally i prefer to use the parse exact method on both the date time. You can use it like so usng your formats above(replace the string dates with your variable as you see fit)

```
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        DateTime thedate = DateTime.ParseExact("2019-10-21 22:05:23", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",provider);
        TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact("14:04:41", @"h\:mm\:ss", provider);
```